# How to make a "next" button appear only after a certain period of time in R Shiny?

Tags: r, shiny

I'm trying to program a page in R Shiny where folks are not shown a question until they have finished watching an embedded video (code below). I've tried this a few ways, but the most intuitive way I could think of was delaying showing the question for the video's runtime.

However, the current code I have here never shows the radioButton() object, no matter how long I wait. If anyone can spot an obvious error in what I'm doing or has a more intuitive way to do this, I'm all ears.

Desired output: A radioButton object that appears after a specified length of time has passed.

```
return(div(fluidPage(
        HTML('<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/-CrOeCzMFSQ?si=3pKfFn_AnvVXKASX" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>'),
        br(),
        
        delay(ms = 200, show(radioButtons(
          "instructions",
          "Have you finished watching the instructions?",
          choices = list(
            "Yes" = 'finished_instructions'),
          width = '100%',
          selected = character(0))))
```

I've tried show(), showElement(), and have been trying this for about a full workday. Still missing something. I'm an R shiny novice, so apologizes if there's an obvious work around.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is also a `shinyjs` solution which shows the button only when the video is finished (without a specific delay).

[image]

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

ui <- fluidPage(
  useShinyjs(),
  uiOutput("video"),
  hidden(
    radioButtons(
      "instructions",
      "Have you finished watching the instructions?",
      choices = list(
        "Yes" = 'finished_instructions'
      ),
      width = '100%',
      selected = character(0)
    )
  )
)
server <- function(input, output) {
  
  output$video <- renderUI({
    HTML(
      '<html>
        <body>
          <iframe id="my-iframe"
              width="560" height="315"
              src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/-CrOeCzMFSQ?si=3pKfFn_AnvVXKASX?&enablejsapi=1" 
              frameborder="0"
              allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen
          ></iframe>
          
          <script type="text/javascript">
            var tag = document.createElement("script");
            tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
            var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
            firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

            var player;
            function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
              player = new YT.Player("my-iframe");
              
              player.addEventListener("onStateChange", function(state){
                if (state.data === 0) {
                  document.getElementById("instructions").classList.remove("shinyjs-hide");
                }
              });
            }  
          </script>
        </body>
      </html>'
    )
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: This is ideal - THANK YOU. I've gotten code like this to work, but I'm randomizing over three possible videos. I find that the instructions don't "show" when I randomize over the three, but do work when I just use a single video. any insights into what might be driving this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78228546/delay-function-in-shinyjs-not-working-when-videos-are-randomized @jan

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use **shinyjs**, you can do:

```r
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

ui <- fluidPage(
  useShinyjs(), # important
  br(),
  HTML('<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/-CrOeCzMFSQ?si=3pKfFn_AnvVXKASX" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>'),
  br(),
  hidden(
    radioButtons(
      "instructions",
      "Have you finished watching the instructions?",
      choices = list(
        "Yes" = 'finished_instructions'
      ),
      width = '100%'
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  delay(10000, show("instructions"))
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```